# Vue.js 2 How can i deal with mouseenter, mouseleave and content dropdown not disappear

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

So guys, how can I use `@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave` but dropdown content, not disappear

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="link" @mouseenter="show = true" @mouseleave="show = false">Item</div>
  <div class="content" v-if="show">This is a content</div>
</div>
```

I tried like this and I got stuck when I want to hover the content or interact with it, I have no idea to handle it, hope y'all can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move `@mouseleave` event to `content`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    show: false,
    links: [1,2,3,4,5],
    linkId: null
  },
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="wrapper" @mouseleave="linkId = null">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="link in links" :key="link">
      <div class="link" @mouseenter.prevent="linkId = link" >Item{{ link }}</div>
      <div class="content" v-if="link === linkId" @mouseleave.prevent="linkId = null">This is a content</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code requires the user enter into the div, the events would be placed on the parent div which wraps both

Comment: Hi @Nikola Pavicevic, how if the link got a v-for? how can I deal with `@mouseleave` inside the content?

Comment: @Dicki Maulana Yusuf , check now mate, I updated answer